# Reset property within lazy getter / after each access

Tags: ios, objective-c

I feel like there is a more regulation way to do what I am doing in, either by some iOS specific thing, or pattern I'm aware of. I'm trying to create an `NSMutableArray` variable, that essentially acts as temporary storage for a logger class. Each time the array is accessed, I want to either lazily instantiate it, or set it to nil. The way I am thinking of doing it seems a little hacky and I'm looking for some input?

```
- (NSMutableArray)myArray {

    if (!_myArray) {
        _myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    } else {
        _myArray = nil;
    }
    return _myArray;
}
```

The effect I'm hoping to achieve is using a logger that is logging details about network requests - `http codes`, `URLs`, repsonse times, etc. I want the logger to amalgamate all this output in this storage `array`. Later on, when I'm hitting an API, I want to take the contents of this array, and send it up to the API, and I also want the array to reset (so the array is essentially a log of network request data since the last time the app hits the API, versus a log of what has happened since the app launched.

I realise that I could do this manually by `nil`ing the `array` when I access it, but I'm trying to do this in a more of a plug and play way, where it you don't need to worry if someone forgets to `nil` the `array` etc

Comment: Agree with @dasblinkenlight. What's the issue you're trying to solve? What is the desired behavior? As it is, you'll merely alternate between `nil` and an empty array each time you call the accessor. That doesn't ***seem*** to be beneficial in any context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effect that you are trying to achieve is perfectly legitimate, but you shouldn't try to achieve it with a getter alone: the very fact that a simple getter could reset something back to `nil` would be counter-intuitive to your readers.

Instead, you should make two methods - one to prepare the array, and another one to harvest it, and replace with a fresh `nil`:

```
- (NSMutableArray*)myArray {
    if (!_myArray) {
        _myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return _myArray;
}
- (NSMutableArray*)resetArray{
    NSMutableArray *res = _myArray;
    _myArray = nil;
    return res;
}
```

Now the sequence of operations becomes intuitively clear: you get `myArray` as many times as you wish, add as many items as you need, and then when you are done call `resetArray`. This would get you a complete array with all the data, and reset the object to be ready for the next call:

```
for (int col = 0 ; col != 10 ; col++) {
    [log.myArray addObject:[self getDataForIndex:col]];
}
NSMutableArray* logArray = [log resetArray];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing doesn't make any sense to me.

Creating it empty if it doesn't exist makes sense.

Setting it to nil if it does exist does **not** make sense.

The usual pattern for lazy loading is to use a property with a getter:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * myArray;
```

and then the implementation:

```
//Custom getter
-(NSMutableArray*) myArray;
{
  if (!_myArray)
    _myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  return _myArray;
}
```

Then you ALWAYS refer to the array using the getter. If it hasn't yet been created, the getter creates and returns the empty array. If it does exist, it returns the existing one.

Comment: I've added some more details to the question Duncan. I'm essentially looking for the array to act as temporary stockpile.

Comment: Still makes no sense. I posted code for a lazy-loading property that follows the usual design pattern. I can't see how your method would be any use, ever.